# PHP CURL Download file to two locations at the same process?

Tags: php, curl

Hi i want to download 1 file with CURL and save it on 1 locations and show it on browser without re-download the file, similar to this:

```
$fp=fopen("cache/".$URL['filename'],"w");
$ch = curl_init($this->URL['href']);
$this->curlOptions[CURLOPT_FILE] = $fp;
curl_setopt_array($ch, $this->curlOptions);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

This example save the file but not showing on browser.

Any help please??

Excuse me, I have not explained well, I need first show in the browser and then save to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a

```
readfile("cache/".$URL['filename']);
```

after the curl_close(). That'll dump the file's contents out to the browser, using the copy you just downloaded/saved.

Comment: Excuse me, I have not explained well, I need the first show in the browser and then save to file

Comment: How does it matter WHEN you save the file? If you're going to send the file to the user who caused the download, you'll first have to download it to your server.

Comment: The purpose is to send the user, while the file downloads to the server

Comment: can't do that. curl doesn't 'return' until the transfer is completed.